# MySql, issue displaying proper video duration when under 60 seconds

Tags: mysql

Video duration format should be 0:00 / 00:00 / 000:00
These work fine, except when the video is less than 60 seconds, it displays as :00

If the video is 12 seconds long, I would like it to show 0:12 but instead it shows :12.

Examples of what I would like: 0:55, 1:55, 11:55, 111:55.

Examples of what I don't want: :55, 01:55, 011:55

Here is the line from my query for the duration:

```
trim(leading 0 from concat( lpad(floor(v.duration/60), 3, 0), ":", lpad((v.duration%60), 2, 0))) as duration
```

Comment: Why are you trimming leading zeroes if you *do* want leading zeroes? And which output do you expect: `0:00` or `00:00` or `000:00` ?

Comment: @RandomSeed The only format I would like to have leading zeros are for durations under 60 seconds. Some examples of what I would like: 0:55, 1:55, 11:55, 111:55. Examples of what I don't want: :55, 01:55, 011:55, etc... I am have tried many solutions before coming here with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a strange stroke of luck I got this working myself using an IF statement, here is the answer for anyone needing this in the future:

```
IF(v.duration/60 < 1, concat(lpad(floor(v.duration/60), 1, 0), ":", lpad((v.duration%60), 2, 0)), trim(leading 0 from concat( lpad(floor(v.duration/60), 3, 0), ":", lpad((v.duration%60), 2, 0)))) as duration
```

This will produce video duration formats from seconds to the following:

0:12

34:56

121:14 (Client requested this format over hh:mm:ss)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it wihout trimming the leading 0

```
 CONCAT(FLOOR(v.duration/60), ":", LPAD((v.duration%60), 2, 0)) as duration
```

Comment: This displays 000:12.

Comment: It solved the issue above, but it now changes longer durations to 003:45 where they should be 3:45. Getting closer though. :)

Comment: Videos less then 60 seconds look like this now: 000

Comment: 0:00 - format is perfect
00:00 - is perfect
000:00 - still shows extra zero at beginning.
For example 013:09

Comment: @Chris check this updated answer now . hope it solves your problem

Comment: I appreciate the effort, however this is not working either. This produces 0:55 (correct), 07:40 (Would like that leading zero gone, but I can live with that), and duration with triple minutes gets cut off, so 117:01 turns into 17:01.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using the built-in formatting functions:

```
select date_format(timestampadd(second, 12, '0000-01-01'), '%H:%i:%s')
```

The challenge (as always it seems with MySQL) is converting between the different time/date data types.  This format adds the duration (which appears to be in seconds) to an early, early date.  It then prints out the format as hh:mm:ss.  You can adjust the format to just show minutes, if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

[Just remove](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c49f/2) the `TRIM` and the first `LPAD`!

```
CONCAT(FLOOR(v.duration/60), ":", LPAD((v.duration%60), 2, 0)) AS duration
```

Answer (score 0):

IT MAKE OUTPUTS FROM **duration** TO **mm:ss**, **hh:mm:ss** and **d hh:mm:ss**

```
SELECT IF(duration<3600,date_format( DATE_ADD('2000-01-01 00:00:00',INTERVAL duration SECOND), '%i:%s'),IF(duration<86400,date_format( DATE_ADD('2000-01-01 00:00:00',INTERVAL duration SECOND), '%H:%i:%s'),CONCAT(floor(duration/86400),' ',date_format( DATE_ADD('2000-01-01 00:00:00',INTERVAL duration SECOND), '%H:%i:%s')))) AS ausgabe
```